# Structs that reference each other

Tags: c, struct

I have two structs that need to reference each other, however whichever one I put first throws and error because I am using an unidentified type.

```
typedef struct _BLOCK
{
    int size;
    int offset;
    struct _BLOCK *nextBlock;
    struct _BLOCK *prevBlock;
    Pool* parent;  //here
} Block;

typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;
    Block* Allocated;
    Block* Unallocated;
} Pool;
```

any ways to resolve this?

Comment: Names starting with `_` followed by an uppercase letter or another underscore are reserved for the implementation. **Don't use them**.

Answer (score 5):

You can use forward declaration.

```
typedef struct _POOL Pool;

typedef struct _BLOCK
{
    int size;
    int offset;
    struct _BLOCK *nextBlock;
    struct _BLOCK *prevBlock;
    Pool* parent;
} Block;

struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;
    Block* Allocated;
    Block* Unallocated;
};
```